# MATLAB - Filling a map with a gradient of two colors based on city colors

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, gradient

I have a map where each city is classified somewhere between r=0 and r=1, which I have plotted in the following image using the color [r 0 1-r], which gives me a color between red and blue for each city. In this case, the circles are just for testing, and should not be visible in the final image. Currently the circle radius represents the amount of data available for each city. The country outline uses the [borders](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50390-borders) data. Here's the result so far:

[image: map]

My goal is to fill the map with a non-linear gradient of red/blue, taking into account this data and extrapolating it.

(In this example the border seems pretty linear, but that's not always the case, hence the need for a non-linear gradient)

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is [`griddata`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html), which lets you interpolate (unevenly) scattered data points using various [interpolation methods](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html#input_argument_d119e381781). So you could evaluate the interpolation on a grid (which can be created using `meshgrid` or `ndgrid`) and then e.g. use `surf` to plot the interpolated function.

Comment: Thank you! That looks promising, I'll try to implement it. Any idea how to restrict the grid to coordinates inside the country outline only?

Comment: I assume you just have a list of vertices that form the country border? You can try `inpolygon`. I recommend just setting the values outside to `NaN` (using logical indexing is easiest) that way you can still use `surf`, `mesh` (which just ignore the `NaN` values)

Comment: Perfect! I ended up using a nearest neighbor interpolation, partially because other interpolation methods don't seem to extrapolate outside the existing data limits, partially because it actually looks better. [Here's the result so far.](https://i.imgur.com/fYVORCV.png)